# Vue Js transition only works when entering, not leaving

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm trying to apply a bottom to top, and top to bottom vue js transition. The bottom to top works on enter, but I get no transition on leave.

Here is my css transition:

```
.slide-details-mobile-enter-active {
    @include transition(all 0.5s ease-in);
}

.slide-details-mobile-enter-active {
    @include transition(all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1));
}

.slide-details-mobile-enter-to, .slide-details-mobile-leave {
    transform: translateY(0vh);
}

.slide-details-mobile-enter, .slide-details-mobile-leave-to {
    transform: translateY(100vh);
}
```

The vue template looks like this:

```
    <transition :name="detailsTransition">
        <sc-fcst-details
            v-if="viewDetails"
            @changeactiveday="changeActiveFcstDay($event)">
        </sc-fcst-details>
    </transition>
```

The first element in the vue template has the following css:

```
#fcst-details {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

Any suggestions on why the leave transition does not work?

Also, I was hoping to use the top style instead of transform, but that wasn't working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working fine for me:

```
.details-transition-enter-active, .details-transition-leave-active {
  transform: translateY(0vh);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.details-transition-enter, .details-transition-leave-to {
  transform: translateY(100vh);
}
```

Give it a go

Later edit (using top instead of transform):

```
.details-transition-enter-active, .details-transition-leave-active {
  top: 0vh;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.details-transition-enter, .details-transition-leave-to {
  top: 100vh;
}
```

And then remove the `top: 0` from `#fcst-details`.

Comment: That worked! Awsome :) Is it possible to use top, instead of transform?